# Can I write Python applications using PyObjC that target NON-jailbroken iPhones?

Tags: iphone, python, pyobjc

Is it currently possible to compile Python and PyObjC for the iPhone such that AppStore applications can written in Python?

If not, is this a purely technical issue or a deliberate policy decision by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: it's Apple's deliberate policy decision (no doubt with some technical underpinnings) to not support interpreters/runtimes on iPhone for most languages -- ObjC (and Javascript within Safari) is what Apple wants you to use, not Python, Java, Ruby, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use PyObjC to write iPhone applications, for the simple reason that PyObjC does not support iOS at all but only targets macOS.

Answer (score -1):

no, apple strictly forbids running any kind of interpreter on iphone, and it is completely policy issue.

Comment: seems like you are not allowed to download new scripts to execute on the phone, but that you are well allowed to run an interpreter.

Comment: Yes I've heard that, Ruby interpreter embedded shiny cocos games seems to be approved by Apple in practice, but agreement is clear so there is a certain risk of application getting pulled.

Answer (score -1):

Yes(mostly). A good way to do this is to use [Pythonista](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097) and its Xcode template.

The other answers here suggesting that such apps are prohibited are based on an accurate-at-the-time ban on "downloading code", but this was never consistently enforced and [it hasn't been in effect for about 7 years](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52161).

This might seem risky since Pythonista has been moribund on the app store for some time; however, while the [Pythonista beta is currently full](https://testflight.apple.com/join/qDkBu2ur) but a new version is coming "soon" that supports Python 3.10.

If you need a more recent version of Python in a more frequently-released app, but don't need the Xcode templates to distribute your app on the app store, you can check out [Pyto](https://pyto.app).

(mostly): It has its own FFI that isn't *quite* PyObjC due to some differendes in the way the runtime is packaged.